# Intellij Not finding Java as a generator. I only have java fx

Tags: java, intellij-idea, generator

After following all the instruction. I have java and IntelliJ in my computer. I've restarted my computer, deleted and reinstalled IntelliJ, still nothing. Furthermore, I can't see java in the generator's section.

Comment: Did you work this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you like to generate a new java project from the Intellij?
Assuming that you just installed Java, you have the 2022.1 version and on this one is enough to add new project and select java from the current menu
[enter image description here][1]

*i would put a comment but i don`t have enough reputation for a simple comment :)*
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2UDF.png

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to start a new java project. I've installed java and IntelliJ. As you can see on the screenshot  in the generator's section there's no java and when  I select like on the screenshot it doesn't appear as java.

Comment: can I contact you personally ?

Comment: sure, type me you`re email